# Is it possible to use A* search for non grid graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding, a-star

I know A* is the most optimal algorithm for finding the shortest path, but I cannot see how any heuristic can work on a non lattice graph? This made me wonder whether or not A* is in fact capable of being used on an undirected or directed graph. If A* is capable of doing this, what kind of heuristic could one use? If A* is not, what is the current fastest algorithm for calculating the shortest path on a directed or undirected non lattice graph? Please comment if any more information is required.

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) gives a few examples. One example is straight line distance for routing, which is not searching in a lattice structure, and is directed. As long as the heuristic is overly optimistic in its estimate it will do fine.

Comment: Although wikipedia does give some examples, what would be the heuristic used for such a graph? How would the algorithm estimate the distance between a given node and an endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible yes, but A* is a popular algorithm for finding shortest paths in grid like graphs. For graphs in general there are a lot of other algorithms for shortest path calculation which will match your case better. It depends on your setting which one to use.

If you plan to do a Single Source Shortest Path (SSSP), where you try to find the shortest path from one node to another one and your graph is unweighted you could use Breath-First-Search. A bidirectional version of this algorithm performs well in practice. If you do SSSP and your graph is weighted Dijkstra's algorithm is a common choice, a bidirectional version could be used as well. For all pairs shortest path other algorithms like Floyd-Warshall or Johnson's algorithm are useful.

If you want to use heuristics and estimate the distance before the search is done you can do pre calculations which are mostly applicable to each of the algorithms mentioned above. Some examples:

- shortcut calculation (ARC-Flags, SHARC, KFlags)
- hub identification (also transite nodes): pre calculate distances between all hub nodes (has to be done only once in non dynamic graphs), find next hub of source and sink e.g. with dijkstra. add up distance between hubs and source to next hub and sink to next hub
- structured look up tables, e.g. distance between hubs and distances between a hub an nodes in a specific distance. After pre calculation you never need to traverse the graph again, instead your shortest path calculation is a number of look-ups. this results in high memory consumption but strong performance. You can tune the memory by using the upper approximations for distance calculations.

I would highly recommend that you identify your exact case and do some research for graph algorithms well suited to this one. A lot of research is done in shortest path for dozens of fields of application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would be a heuristic that one could use on a directed graph? Most heuristics assume the fact that the distance between a given node and the endpoint is known. In a directed graph, this information is not known. Do you know of any heuristics that can do this?

Comment: Could you be more clear? All of them are pre calculations. The method of hub identification could be used as a heuristic one. You only calculate the shortest path of a Node A to the next Hub Node HA (you may also pre calculate that), the same is done for a Node B and we call the node HB. Now you only have to calculate SSSP between HA and HB and in the end you add up the distances from A -> HA -> HB -> B. This is not necessarily optimal but very fast for transition networks. What is your scenario?

Comment: did that answer your question or is something unclear? feel free to ask, if that helped you consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer